# Applescript - Organize files into folders according to their names

Tags: applescript

I found this post: [Applescript - Creating folders based on the first word of the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093864/applescript-creating-folders-based-on-the-first-word-of-the-filename#new-answer)
 after some research looking for something similar, but with more steps involved.
First of all, I'm new to applescript. I'm kind of able to see a code and understand part of what it does, but not everything.

I have a bunch of pdf files named like so:
Category1 Category2 Category3 RestofTheName.pdf
As you can imagine the name of each category may vary from one bunch of pdfs to another.

I want to organize them in folders, as the script above does.
Then I  want to remove the first word of each pdf (Since the part CategoryX is given to the file name only for organization purposes). I have acomplished that with the code below:

```
###################################################
#################### CATEGORY1 #######################
###################################################

###########################################################
# Organize files of a chosen folder using the first word of each file as name of the sub folders #
###########################################################

set chosenFolder to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of chosenFolder

set TID to text item delimiters

set text item delimiters to space
repeat with aFile in fileList
    set fileName to name of aFile
    set textItems to text items of fileName
    if (count textItems) = 1 then
        set fileExtension to name extension of aFile
        set folderName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExtension in fileName) - 1) of fileName
    else
        set folderName to first item of textItems
    end if
    set sourceFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (aFile as text)
    set destinationFile to quoted form of (POSIX path of chosenFolder & folderName & "/" & fileName)
    do shell script "ditto " & sourceFile & space & destinationFile
    do shell script "rm " & sourceFile
end repeat

set text item delimiters to TID

#####################################
# Remove first word of if each file inside every sub folder  #
#####################################

set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "

set pFolder to chosenFolder

processThisFolder(pFolder)

on processThisFolder(sourceFolder)
    set the theList to list folder sourceFolder without invisibles
    set sourceFolder to sourceFolder as string

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theList
        set thisItem to item i of theList
        set thisItem to (sourceFolder & thisItem) as alias
        set thisItemInfo to info for thisItem
        set isFolder to folder of thisItemInfo

        if isFolder is true then
            processThisFolder(thisItem)

        else
            set thisFileName to name of thisItemInfo
            #set withoutPrefix to text item -last text item) of thisFileName    -- solo deja la ultima palabra
            set withoutPrefix to text from text item 2 to -1 of thisFileName

            tell application "Finder"
                set name of thisItem to withoutPrefix
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat

end processThisFolder
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
```

So far so good. The thing is that now I'd like to keep organizing the pdf files. I want the script to go through every folder created during the first step, and check again for the first word of each file name (which originally was the second) and move them into folders. And them have it to remove the first word again.

Then do this step one more time. So I'd end up with this estructure:

```
+ Category1 Folder1
  - Category2 Folder1
    · Category 3 Folder1
       RestofTheName1.pdf
       RestofTheName2.pdf
       RestofTheName3.pdf
       RestofTheName4.pdf
       RestofTheName5.pdf

    · Category 3 Folder2
    · Category 3 Folder3

  - Category2 Folder2
    · Category 3 Folder1
    · Category 3 Folder2

+ Category1 Folder2
  - Category2 Folder1
  - Category2 Folder2
  - Category2 Folder3
  - Category2 Folder4
```

Since the first part works fine, I guess it's matter of repeating the steps: organize, rename, organize, rename. But as the folder structure is growing with each step, I can't seem to get the script to act on the right folder/subfolders/files....

This is where I'm at now:

```
# CATEGORY1 

# Organize files of a chosen folder using the first word of each file as name of the sub folders 
###########################################################

set chosenFolder to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of chosenFolder

set TID to text item delimiters

set text item delimiters to space
repeat with aFile in fileList
    set fileName to name of aFile
    set textItems to text items of fileName
    if (count textItems) = 1 then
        set fileExtension to name extension of aFile
        set folderName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExtension in fileName) - 1) of fileName
    else
        set folderName to first item of textItems
    end if
    set sourceFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (aFile as text)
    set destinationFile to quoted form of (POSIX path of chosenFolder & folderName & "/" & fileName)
    do shell script "ditto " & sourceFile & space & destinationFile
    do shell script "rm " & sourceFile
end repeat

set text item delimiters to TID


# Remove first word of if each file inside every sub folder  #
###########################################################

set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "

set pFolder to chosenFolder

processThisFolder(pFolder)

on processThisFolder(sourceFolder)
    set the theList to list folder sourceFolder without invisibles
    set sourceFolder to sourceFolder as string

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theList
        set thisItem to item i of theList
        set thisItem to (sourceFolder & thisItem) as alias
        set thisItemInfo to info for thisItem
        set isFolder to folder of thisItemInfo

        if isFolder is true then
            processThisFolder(thisItem)

        else
            set thisFileName to name of thisItemInfo
            set withoutPrefix to text from text item 2 to -1 of thisFileName

            tell application "Finder"
                set name of thisItem to withoutPrefix
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat

end processThisFolder
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims



# CATEGORY2

# Organize files inside every subfolder using the first word of each file name (which used to be the second word) as name of the sub sub folders 
###########################################################################################



tell application "Finder" to set subFoldersLevel1 to every folder of (entire contents of (chosenFolder))

set TID to text item delimiters

set text item delimiters to space
repeat with aFile in fileList
    set fileName to name of aFile
    set textItems to text items of fileName
    if (count textItems) = 1 then
        set fileExtension to name extension of aFile
        set folderName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExtension in fileName) - 1) of fileName
    else
        set folderName to first item of textItems
    end if
    set sourceFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (aFile as text)
    set destinationFile to quoted form of (POSIX path of chosenFolder & folderName & "/" & fileName)
    do shell script "ditto " & sourceFile & space & destinationFile
    do shell script "rm " & sourceFile
end repeat

set text item delimiters to TID
```

Any help is welcome!!

Comment: How are you determining what the name is vs the category?  Are there a fixed number of category names or some kind of delimiter?

Comment: Ok, I'm a graphic designer, and the names of the files will be different from one job to another. Lets say each pdf will be a leaflet. And each one of them will have something that makes them different from all the others.
If the job is about animals the names could be things like:

```
FourLegs BigOnes Horses NameOfHorse.pdf
FourLegs SmallOnes Cats NameOfCat.pdf
TwoLegs SmallOnes Birds NameOfBird.pdf
```
So categories and names will depend on the nature of the job itself. And there is no limit of categories, each job could have different ammount of them.
I hope I understood  right.

Comment: I was mainly asking how you are determining the "name" vs the categories, for example, what would you be using to determine the name for `FourLegs BigOnes Horses Italian Heavy Draft`?  Does each file name consist of single (upper/lower camel case) words separated by spaces, with the last one being the name you want to keep?

Comment: Ok. In my example I was working with 3 category levels and everything after the first 3 words was the file name, being it one word or more.
But depending on the job, I could have more or less categories, even though I don't think I'd ever need more than 5 or 6 category levels. As a matter of fact, I was thinking it would be great to have the script ask you how many categories the job has, so it works in every scenario.

Comment: About lower and upper case, I was using the  upper/lower camel case system but I could use under scores if it's easier, my point was to keep  categories with two words as one string with no spaces.
When exporting the pdfs I can choose the categories to be all lower case if it's easier, but I'd rather have them as first character with upper case and the rest lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get too crazy with text delimiters, recursive handlers, or whatever.  If the components of the original file name are words separated by spaces, you can just use those spaces to determine the categories.  In the following example I get the *words* (text separated by whitespace and various punctuation) of the file name and use a shell script to make a directory structure from them:

```
on run -- example
    set chosenFolder to (choose folder)
    tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of chosenFolder as alias list
    set skippedItems to ""
    repeat with anItem in fileList
        set theResult to process(anItem)
        if theResult is not "" then set skippedItems to skippedItems & theResult
    end repeat
    if skippedItems is not "" then display alert "Items were skipped:" message skippedItems
end run

# Create a directory structure from words of the file name and move/rename last item.
to process(theFile)
    set {folderPath, fileName, extension} to getNamePieces from theFile
    try -- guard
        set theWords to words 1 thru -2 of fileName
        set subdirectories to ""
        repeat with anItem in theWords -- build a directory tree from the words
            set subdirectories to subdirectories & anItem & "/"
        end repeat
        do shell script "cd " & quoted form of folderPath & "; mkdir -p " & subdirectories
        tell application "System Events" to set name of (move theFile to disk item (folderPath & "/" & subdirectories)) to (last word of fileName) & extension
    on error errmess -- skip it (no words - underscore separator, etc)
        log errmess
        return (fileName & extension & return)
    end try
    return ""
end process

#  Get posix path of the containing folder, the file name, and the extension.
to getNamePieces from someItem
    tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (someItem as text)
        set theContainer to POSIX path of container
        set {theName, theExtension} to {name, name extension}
    end tell
    if theExtension is not "" then
        set theName to text 1 thru -((count theExtension) + 2) of theName -- the name part
        set theExtension to "." & theExtension
    end if
    return {theContainer, theName, theExtension}
end getNamePieces
```

Comment: I can't give it a try until Monday. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was testing yesterday and it works great.
I really appreciate it.